# What does it mean "to=" when creating model field in django?

Tags: django-models, django-4.0

Are those tree ways giving the same result/field, is there any other way?

```
    class Message(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(to=User)
```

```
        user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

```
        user = models.ForeignKey("User")
```

Comment: Yes, although the first requires to import a model named user, and is thus vulnerable to cyclic imports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are those tree ways giving the same result/field

**Yes**, although the first requires to import a model named user, and is thus vulnerable to cyclic imports.

> is there any other way?

The advised way is to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly, so:

```
from django.conf import settings


class Message(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).